# mySQL: Looking for query/sql solution for daily statistic in transaction table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 'transactions' table with columns like: **transactionDateTime, quantity, price, clientName, sellerName, transactionType (sell/buy)**....

Right now I'm listing all those transactions in table on web page (php). I want to add to the list **daily summary per 'seller' per transaction type (buy or sell)**. So at very minimum I'm looking for query that will do the summary using the table, at maximum (not sure if that possible) a query that does same plane list as I had before plus the summary results once transactionDateTime turns to new day.

Thank you in advance.

Sample of transactions table:

> transactionDateTime, quantity, price, clientName, stationID,
>   transactionType, seller, typeID

- '2014-01-04 05:44:02', '2630', '150.00', 'ClientA', '60014917','buy', 'SellerA', '2399'
- '2014-01-04 05:41:02', '2630', '50.00', 'ClientB', '60014914','buy', 'SellerA', '2398'
- '2014-01-04 04:23:45', '2','1900000.00', 'ClientC', '60014056','sell', 'SellerA', '27918'
- '2014-01-04 01:08:33', '3', '2949499.99', 'ClientD', '60014056','sell', 'SellerB', '31119'
- '2014-01-01 15:57:35', '1', '168999999.99', 'ClientE', '60014917','sell', 'SellerA','19281'
- '2014-01-01 13:00:18', '1', '38999999.00','ClientF', '60014917', 'sell', 'SellerB', '14206'

Right now I'm listing almost unprocessed row data on webpage.
What I want should look like same list + summary for each day. Like:

- Summary '2014-01-04': SellerA, Buy = (2630*150+2630*50)
- Summary '2014-01-04': SellerA, Sell = (2*1900000)
- Summary '2014-01-04': SellerB, Sell = (3*2949499.99)
- '2014-01-04 05:44:02', '2630', '150.00', 'ClientA', '60014917', 'buy', 'SellerA', '2399'
- '2014-01-04 05:41:02', '2630', '50.00', 'ClientB', '60014914', 'buy', 'SellerA', '2398'
- '2014-01-04 04:23:45', '2', '1900000.00', 'ClientC', '60014056', 'sell', 'SellerA', '27918'
- '2014-01-04 01:08:33', '3', '2949499.99', 'ClientD', '60014056', 'sell', 'SellerB', '31119'
- Summary '2014-01-01': SellerA, Sell = (1*168999999.99)
- Summary '2014-01-01': SellerB, Sell = (1*38999999.00)
- '2014-01-01 15:57:35', '1', '168999999.99', 'ClientE', '60014917', 'sell', 'SellerA', '19281'
- '2014-01-01 13:00:18', '1', '38999999.00', 'ClientF', '60014917', 'sell', 'SellerB', '14206'

Is it even possible in SQL query? Or should I do that by programming methods?

Comment: What have you tried?  It is a good idea to put some effort into solving a problem before asking a question.

Comment: Gordon, I don't have anything to mention as "tried". Cause what I want is beyong my SQL knowlede.

Comment: In that case, you can at least add in some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
/* Your details. */
select 'DETAIL' type_of_record
,      1 sorting_order
,      something_to_order_details_on sorting_order_detail
,      transactionType
,      sellerName
,      transactionDateTime
,      quantity
,      price
from   transactions
union
all
/* Your totals. */
select 'DAILY' type_of_record
,      2 sorting_order
,      null sorting_order_detail
,      transactionType
,      sellerName
,      trunc(transactionDateTime) /* Or whatever MySQL uses to round dates. */
,      sum(quantity) quantity_sum
,      sum(price) price_sum
from   transactions
where  transactionDateTime < trunc(now)
order
by     sorting_order
,      sorting_order_detail
```

Comment: Thank you, Guido! My SQL knowledge is limited, obviusely, so it will take a bit to digest the answer :) At my first look your 4th line from bottom tells me that result will be transactions for today + the summary i wanted for today. (I might be wrong cause I'm SQL newbie). Am I right? I was looking for something that will list: summary 2014.02.02 PersonA Sell, summary 2014.02.02 PersonA Buy, summary 2014.02.02 PersonB Sell, summary 2014.02.02 PersonB Buy, transactcion#2014.02.02,transactcion#2014.02.02,summary 2014.02.01 PersonA Sell,summary 2014.02.01 PersonA Buy,transactcion#2014.02.01, etc

Comment: But I guess it is good thing to start with! It would be priceless if you could comment it somehow for better understanding.

Comment: adding comments is quite hard since it is already condensed very much, but the first part of the union gives the detail rows and the part after 'union all' the grouped output. The rest is just using SQL. When it is usable, please signal such by checking the hollow check mark. When you need additional input, for instance with sample data, please add the sample data to your question. That makes the results more usable for future visitors.

Comment: Just got your query working in my context. It didn't give me exact what I was looking for. So yes! I'll add sample data to the question.

Comment: added data and desired output